# How to check for overfitting using RMSE?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have the code below to check for overfitting using R^2. I am trying to use the same code to check for overfitting using RMSE not R^2. The default scorer for `.score` is R^2. How can I do that?

```
cv = KFold(n_splits=5, random_state=0,shuffle=True)

train_scores, test_scores = [], []

for train, test in cv.split(X_normalized):
    X_transform2 = poly.fit_transform(X_normalized)
    OL = lin_regressor.fit(X_transform2[train], y_for_normalized.iloc[train])
    tr_21 = OL.score(X_transform2[train], y_for_normalized.iloc[train])
    ts_21 = OL.score(X_transform2[test], y_for_normalized.iloc[test])
    print("Train score:", tr_21)  # from documentation .score returns r^2
    print("Test score:", ts_21)  # from documentation .score returns r^2

    train_scores.append(tr_21)
    test_scores.append(ts_21)


print("The Mean for Train scores is:", (np.mean(train_scores)))

print("The Mean for Test scores is:", (np.mean(test_scores)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, you can't get other kinds of score from the `.score()` method.

You'll need to either make a prediction and score it yourself, e.g. with (the square root of) [`sklearn.metrics.mean_squared_error()`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.mean_squared_error.html) or by using one of the cross validation workflow helpers like [`sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score()`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html), which you can ask for different scores or use your own scoring function.

For example, in your CV loop you could do something like this:

```py
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

X_test = X_transform2[test]
y_test = y_for_normalized.iloc[test]

y_pred_ts = OL.predict(X_test)
ts_21_rmse = np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred_ts))
```

You will find [the `sklearn` User Guide](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html) to be an excellent source of information on this and most other basic ML topics.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for. Just one last question, I am assuming that this returns a positive number not a negative one like the `scoring` parameter (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html) in sklearn because in the documentation for the `sklearn.metrics.mean_squared_error` (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.mean_squared_error.html) it says: "it returns a non-negative floating point value (the best value is 0.0), or an array of floating point values, one for each individual target." Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Right, the MSE is always positive (the errors are squared, so they have to be positive). The RMSE is nice because it's in the same units as `y`, so I find it easier to interpret.